# Can i parent child bones in animations?

Tags: animation

So, i rigged my mesh, and started making some animations, just to check if everything i did was working OK and porting to unity in the right format, so i can keep doing more stuff. (No point in working in clothing if the base body wasnt working, etc)
Problem is, i made some animations during the week, and today i started adding bones for facial expression, and even tho they are child bones from the head bone, they are at the original position and not traslated in the animations with the head.

So my question is, is there any way to make all the bones in the face, keep kinda locked into the base-face position? so when i move the head they move together? 
Just for the lols, this is how it looks with the bones in the wrong positions
[image]

truly a hideous view.

Or, if i can't set the face-bones to move together and keep position with the head one, is there any other/better way to make facial expressions?

Comment: I don't understand, if these bones are children of the head bone, they should follow the head bone, even if you've created them afterwards...

Comment: yeah, i rechecked after reading your comment and turns out they werent parented, so... i failed very hard there. Thanks for the help